# iPhone ModalViewController not navigating to next view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a ModalViewController that is displayed from the App Delegate. The ModalViewController launches fine, and will execute various actions such as [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; as expected.

the dismiss works, but I am not able to get the ModalViewController to navigate/slide to the next view. I am not receiving any errors or warnings in my code.

```
-(IBAction)signUpButtonTapped {
    // i need to get the control for main navigation controller
    HHHTabAppDelegate *appDelegate = (HHHTabAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [appDelegate.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    // create object from app main view to push it
    SignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
    [appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:signUpViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For pop and push viewControllers, you need to set previously the navigation controller.
[Here](http://theolternative.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/iphone-dev-tips-navigation-and-tap-bar-controller/) you can find a tutorial about how to create a nav controller without a xib or storyboard.

Comment: Checking it out now. Do you need to set the navigationController in the same .m file as the code I posted is in? Or do i need to put it in the SignUpViewController (the page being pushed to)?

Comment: But if your first view controller is presented modally, you should do it on the first

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to be presenting a `UINavigationController` rather than a `SignupViewController` when you open the modal view for the first time.  Code could look something like this:

```
ModalViewController *modalViewController = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *modalNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:modalViewController];

[appDelegate.navigationController presentModalViewController:modalNavController animated:YES];
```

Your problem is that you are sending the push message to a nil instance of `UINavigationController`.